# XPATH - grab contents of div futher down the page

Tags: html

I want to grab the movie titles from a page, which has numerous divs like this one:

[image]

So any text that contains the word "stars" and then the movie under it, so I get the movie and the rating.

I got this bit:

```
//span[contains(., 'stars')]
```

Which grabs all the texts for the movies. but cannot grab the title:

```
//span[contains(., 'stars')]/following-sibling::div/div/div/a
```

Comment: Could you add a little bit more context ? Are you trying to read data from and HTML page or a XML document.

Comment: This is an html webpage.

Answer (score 0):

here's how you should do this.

```
//span[contains(., 'stars')]/parent::div/following-sibling::div/a
```